# (OAuthException) (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: stream.removeComment

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

In my one of .Net Application I want to delete comments of facebook user who is logged in. For this purpose Im getting Post id of that comment and also uid of that user and AccessToken And My Application Also Have its Extended Permission of "Publish Stream" for this Operation

As mentioned on facebook Developer site. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.removeComment/

I am using facebook sdk for .NET to request the facebook api from my application.

```
        try
            {
                var fwb = new FacebookClient(AccesToken);
                Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                parameters.Add("comment_id", comment_id);
                parameters.Add("uid", Convert.ToInt64(uid));
                dynamic result = fwb.Post("stream.removeComment", parameters);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblError.Text = ex.Message;
            }
```

And I Got This Exception. 
"(OAuthException) (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: stream.removeComment"

Please Help Me If Some One No Knows About That Issue. 
Thanks

Comment: Can You Please Elaborate More. How I Mixed Both Rest And Graph. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are mixing graph api and rest api. change it to the following code

```
parameters.Add("method", "stream.removeContent");
dynamic result = fwb.Post(parameters);
```